# Html.Select doesn't exist

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-3.5

I am trying to get an old application, that was written using a mvc preview version, to run with version mvc-2 and have run in the following problem.

```
<%= Html.Select("categorie", ViewData.Model.Categories, "naam", "categorieId", null, 1, false, new { prompt = "== geen filter =="} )%>
```

Now I get the message that Html.Select doesn't exist, I assume that there was either a name change or it was removed.

My question is how do I resolve this? Either by new function name or using a different method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Html.DropDownList, Html.DropDownListFor. See html helpers [overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493063.aspx)

Comment: Could you give me an example because i cant seem to figure it out